# A hitting time of an open set for a càdlàg process is a stopping time

Tags: stochastic-processes, continuous-time, stopping-time

In Protter *Stochastic Integration and Differential Equations*, Springer (2003), the following definition is given:

**Definition.** Let $X$ be a stochastic process and let $\Delta$ be a Borel set in $\mathbb{R}$.
Define
$$
T(\omega) = \inf \{t > 0 : X_t \in \Delta \},
$$
Then $T$ is a **hitting time** of $\Delta$ for $X$.

Then the following theorem is stated:

**Theorem** Let $X$ be an adapted càdlàg stochastic process, and let $\Delta$ be an open set. Then the hitting time of $\Delta$ is a stopping time.

In the proof, Protter states that it is sufficient to show that $\{T < t\} \in \mathcal{F}_t$ for $0 \leq t < \infty$ (under the condition that $\mathcal{F}_t$ is right-continuous).

However, he then states that:

$$
\{T < t\} = \bigcup_{s \in \mathbb{Q}\cap[0,t)} \{X_s \in \Delta\}
$$
"since $\Delta$ is an open set and $X$ has right continuous paths".
I do not manage to understand this last equality, even with that explanation.

Could someone help me to understand it?

Thanks

Comment: You just need to show that both sides are mutually subset of each other, given the density of $\mathbb{Q}$ in $\mathbb{R}$.